# OData endpoint: Is it possible to edit document service

Tags: model-view-controller, http-headers, odata

Dears,

I've designed a OData endpoint, following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint
I'm done with it but I have a constraint: for all API features, the header must contain an Authorization key. This is done everywhere BUT in the service document. The service document is what you got when looking at URL https://SITE/api/v1:

```
{"@odata.context":"http://SITE/api/v1/$metadata","value":[{"name":"things","kind":"EntitySet","url":"things"},{"name":"others","kind":"EntitySet","url":"others"}]}
```

Hence, do you know how is generated such document service? Is it possible to edit it? Or even, is there way to check header in such a document service?
Thanks in advance for your help,

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself using following module:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Api.Modules
{
    public class AuthorizationModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose(){}

        private void Context_Authorization(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
            if (!IsAuthorized(application.Context))
            {
                application.Context.Response.Status = "403 Forbidden";
                application.Context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                application.CompleteRequest();
            }
        }

        public bool IsAuthorized(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Authorization"))
                return false;

            string authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

            if (!authHeader.Equals(Properties.Resources.Authorization_Key))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.AuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(Context_Authorization);
        }
    }
}
```

If it helps...

Kind regards,